# How can I make an element in the middle if the whole page become become fixed

Tags: css, media-queries

I have an element in the middle of the page somewhere and i want it to have a fixed position at the top when the user scrools down and the element reaches the top.

I don't know if it can be done with media query.
Like
@ height 90rem from top of page:

```css
.element{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Comment: No, a media query can _not_ do this. Go look into `position: sticky`.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `position: sticky;`.
Try:

```
position: sticky; 
top: 0px;
```